# How to get results from Facebook Insights API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to get useful data from the Insights section using the the Graph API Explorer.

I've tried different metrics and dates, and the results for data is always empty.

I was able to look at my page dashboard for number of likes and select a range based on that, but I still don't see any data.

If the access_key is an issue, would it return an error saying so, or just return empty results?

Here is the debug output from a popular company that I would imagine has new likes in the past few weeks.

```
=== Query
  curl -i -X GET \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/14226545351/insights/page_positive_feedback_by_type?since=1487788679&until=1490812690&access_token=<access token sanitized>"
=== Access Token Info
  {
    "perms": [
      "user_likes",
      "manage_pages",
      "pages_show_list",
      "public_profile"
    ],
    "page_id": 167544343274096,
    "user_id": "10152810337959467",
    "app_id": 145634995501895
  }
=== Parameters
- Query Parameters

  {
    "since": "1487788679",
    "until": "1490812690"
  }
- POST Parameters

  {}
=== Response
  {
    "data": [],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/14226545351/insights?access_token=<access token sanitized>&pretty=0&since=1484764668&until=1487788679&metric=page_positive_feedback_by_type",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/14226545351/insights?access_token=<access token sanitized>&pretty=0&since=1490812690&until=1493836701&metric=page_positive_feedback_by_type"
    },
    "__debug__": {}
  }
=== Debug Information from Graph API Explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=14226545351%2Finsights%2Fpage_positive_feedback_by_type%3Fsince%3D1487788679%26until%3D1490812690&version=v2.8
```

Is anyone able to give an actual working example? I have not come across any yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered in the Graph API explorer, when you generate an access token, you need to give it permission "read_insights".

Also, this will only work on a page which your account has access to that given object.

Unfortunately the documentation is pretty vague in this area and there was no permissions error message give.

Comment: What is “vague” about “A page access token with read_insights permission can retrieve all metrics for that Page.” ...?
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/insights#reading

Comment: @CBroeThe API documentation is vague in terms of the definitions for each property. The issue I had with troubleshooting was due to no error message for invalid permissions.

Comment: I was vague myself about what was vague. But I found it frustrating pouring through all the facebook graph api documentation in general to find what I need.

Comment: My App is in developer mode and I am getting this as reponse. Can anybody help?   {
    "data": [],
    "paging": {
        "previous": "graphurl/objectid/insights?access_token=XXXXX&since=1584514800&until=1585810800&metric=post_impressions_fan%2Cpost_engaged_users",
        "next": "graphurl/objectid/insights?access_token=XXXXX&since=1587106800&until=1588402800&metric=post_impressions_fan%2Cpost_engaged_users"
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late, but better late then never I guess :)

On [this Facebook docs page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/insights) you can find a list of all the metrics you can use.

As for empty data, I had the same problem. I could never find how to get data from Facebook Insights; but thanks to the cheatsheet, I can give you an example:

### Facebook Insights Example

`https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}?fields=insights.metric(page_fans)&access_token={access_token}`

**EDIT**

Also, user [Ravi Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6102412/ravi-patel) has a great, working example showing how to get insights from your posts:

`/{page-id}/posts?fields=insights.metric(post_impressions_fan,post_engaged_users)`

[Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51184669/10133180)