# Facebook API query sub-object

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am interested in getting post lifetime insights for a given page in a single request.

A previous issue did half the work: [Get posts with insights from a single API call - Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674315/get-posts-with-insights-from-a-single-api-call-facebook-graph-api)

Which allows me to get the insights for all posts in a single request by doing:

```
/{page-id}/posts?fields=insights.metric(post_impressions_fan,post_engaged_users)
```

But these are not always lifetime insights, and I would like to specify `period=lifetime` for the sub object.

How can I in Facebook Graph API do such?

I tried:

- Adding `insights.period(lifetime)` which errors with: "Field insights specified more than once. This is only possible before version 2.1"
- Doing insights only once as `insights{metric(post_impressions_fan,post_engaged_users),period(lifetime)}` but that failed with "Expected end of string instead of \"(\"."

Comment: What do you mean, _“these are not always lifetime insights”_? Specifically those two metrics you are requesting here are _only_ available for the lifetime period to begin with, and nothing else.

Comment: Anyway, `insights.metric(abc).period(xyz)` should work.

Comment: I use other metrics not only those. Thanks, that indeed works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API call to get lifetime post insight:

```
{page_id}/posts?fields=id,name,type,shares,link,permalink_url,created_time,picture,comments.summary(true).limit(0),likes.summary(true).limit(0),reactions.summary(true).limit(0)&period=lifetime&limit=100
```

use pagination to get all the post since maximum limit we can set is 100.