# '(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (posts) on node type (PagePost)' when getting page post insights

Tags: facebook-graph-api

From [Get posts with insights from a single API call - Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51184669/3416774), the suggested query is:

```
/{page-id}/posts?fields=insights.metric(post_impressions_fan,post_engaged_users)
```

I use the API explorer but it returns this error:

```
(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (posts) on node type (PagePost)
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Your `{page-id}` is clearly _not_ that, but the ID of an individual post already. It is telling you right there at the end of the error message, _what_ you are trying to request these fields on: `on node type (PagePost)`